# Kindle Create and full page images

Tags: kindle, image, page-size

I use the kindle plugin for MS Word and Kindle Create from Amazon. I have several images in my book, which I want to always take up a full page with maximum size (margins are okay), independent of the chosen font size.
How can I do that? In both kindle previews which are provided by word and kindle create, the images resizes randomly if I change the font size. Even though if I choose the "full size" option in kindle create. What am I missing?

I guess it might be saving me some frustration if I would just hard code those ebook files. Any recommendations for free software making this more convenient than a text editor?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is not a software solution to this problem because you have to design a responsive solution that works in various display sizes. Fixed layout solutions like Kindle Create may work in one display but not others. It is designed for simple ebooks; images involve some sophisticated css.

I wrote a code solution for the problem of image size on Kindle: https://www.reddit.com/r/selfpublish/comments/991c1h/what_is_the_ideal_image_size_for_kindle/e4t5oca/